# Javascript Integers vs Floating Point memory - do number of decimal places affect memory?

Tags: javascript, memory-management, floating-point, integer, decimal

Have some svg files with many points, running lots of calculations on these values...trying to optimize calculations and memory:

Floating Point values store twice as much memory as integers:

`// 5 is less memory than 5.6789`

What about within Floating Point values - do fewer decimal places require less memory?

`// Does 5.12 require less memory than 5.12341234647839234798372938719`?

EDIT: removed PI and replaced with generic random number.

Comment: All JavaScript numbers are 64-bit floating point, so they all take up the same amount of memory. Your many-digit pi value cannot be represented exactly.

Comment: Note that some new runtimes also support "big integers", and those do vary in size according to the magnitude of the value.

Comment: @Pointy apologies I removed PI and replaced with a different random number.

Comment: Well the point remains: there's limited precision for long fractional parts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`Number` type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) is double-precision 64-bit IEEE 754 binary floating point. All values (from 5 to 5.12341234647839234798372938719) occupy the same amount of memory (eight raw bytes of memory, with possible overhead from object wrapping, depending on engine), but precision is limited; the literal `5.12341234647839234798372938719` is expressing false precision (e.g. `5.12341234647839234798372938718` is the same value).

Comment: ah thanks that's what I was looking for - so 5 and 5.123123123123 occupy the same 8 raw bytes of memory.



So then in terms of calculations - 5 * 5 and 5 * 5.12341234647839234798372938719 is really just 8 bytes of memory multiplied by a different 8 bytes of memory? 

In other words: there's no benefit in rounding my values down from 5.12341234647839234798372938719 to 5.12 (other than being more human-readable)?

Comment: @jared yes correct. Concievably in particular situations the runtime could optimize and store values as small integers, but I'm pretty sure that those would be very localized cases where memory use is mostly irrelevant

Comment: @Pointy: asm.js (a predecessor to WebAssembly that runs simplified JS as a kind of assembly language) takes advantage of optimizing JS engines to achieve benefits of that sort (typically by inserting `|0` operations all over the place to enforce integer context, because `|0` is a complete no-op aside from implying integer context), but yeah, the benefits are more about avoiding floating point precision issues by translating to (often slightly faster) integer instructions than about memory usage.

Comment: @ShadowRanger right that's what I'm talking about. Even without Web Assembly a runtime could determine that (for example) a loop index variable is going to only have integer values.